# Small tab on Chrome browser using JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I just wanted to ask about the image below. I'm currently building a Chrome extension that opens the LinkedIn tab in a "small tab" style like the image below. I can't find any reference to this on other sites. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this using either Chrome APIs or JavaScript? I really need to learn how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance for the upcoming answers!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using the [`chrome.tabs` API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs).
Specifically, the [`chrome.tabs.create(..)`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-create) function.

If you take a look at the documentation, the create function accepts as the first parameter the new tab's properties, the propriety that you're interested in is `pinned`.

That means that in order to get the desired effect, you need to use something like this:

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'https://linkedin.com', pinned: true });
```